# How to ensure that multiple documents are saved?

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to implement many-to-many relationship. The code below works just fine, but I'm worried that under some circumstances it might fail. For example, if the server is overloaded and one save operation fails — it would leave me with only one document in the database. One solution to this would be to use [transactions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html). Transaction lets execute multiple operations in isolation and potentially undo all the operations if one of them fails. In the docs I stumbled upon this line:

> MongoDB currently only supports transactions on replica sets, not standalone servers

From what I understand I use a standalone server and therefore I can't use transactions.
What are my options? Any advice?

```
  const AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    books: [{ type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book' }]
  })
  const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    authors: [{ type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }]
  })
  const Author = mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema)
  const Book = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema)

  const author = new Author({ name: 'Batman' })
  const book = new Book({ title: 'How to cook a bat and not cause a pandemic' })

  author.books.push(book._id)
  book.authors.push(author._id)

  await author.save()
  await book.save()
```